# mysql query to required to be faster

Tags: mysql, sql, database-administration

Hi Is it possible to speed the following query up? I have tried using different indexes, Would I be right in thinking that If its constantly taking more than 0.20 seconds that the query cache is not being used?

Also is forcing an index a good idea in this case? 
FYI all three columns used after the where clause are indexed.

```
mysql> SELECT count( item_t0.PK ) FROM table item_t0 WHERE ( item_t0.PK <>87984555070 AND  item_t0.p_internalurl ='replicated273784712' AND ( item_t0.p_datapk =8987719073822 OR ( item_t0.p_datapk  IS NULL AND  item_t0.PK =8987719073822))) AND (item_t0.TypePkString IN  (N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N) );
    +---------------------+
    | count( item_t0.PK ) |
    +---------------------+
    |                   0 |
    +---------------------+
    1 row in set (0.32 sec)


mysql> explain extended SELECT count( item_t0.PK ) FROM medias item_t0 WHERE ( item_t0.PK <>8798340055070 AND  item_t0.p_internalurl ='replicated273654712' AND ( item_t0.p_datapk =8987719073822 OR ( item_t0.p_datapk  IS NULL AND  item_t0.PK =8987717719073822))) AND (item_t0.TypePkString IN  (N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N) );                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 7961003
+----+-------------+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------+-------+-------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys                                          | key             | key_len | ref   | rows  | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------+-------+-------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | item_t0 | ref  | PRIMARY,dataPK_idx_30,internalurl_idx,typepkstring_idx | internalurl_idx | 768     | const | 74102 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------+-------+-------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

I have looked at whether the query_cache needs to be looked into and saw the following values, Can anyone suggest if the following results show anything...

```
  mysql> show global status like "%Qcache_hits%";
    +---------------+--------+
    | Variable_name | Value  |
    +---------------+--------+
    | Qcache_hits   | 352251 |
+---------------+--------+

mysql> show global status like "%com_select%";
+---------------+----------+
| Variable_name | Value    |
+---------------+----------+
| Com_select    | 33525493 |
+---------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show global status like "%prunes%";
+----------------------+----------+
| Variable_name        | Value    |
+----------------------+----------+
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes | 15729370 |
+----------------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: `<>` will not use an index and `OR`ed conditions are also bad, you might try rewriting it as two `UNION`ed Selects.

Comment: `item_t0.TypePkString IN  (N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,N)` seems weird> what is that? It even does not seem to be correct syntax as string values should be sigle quoted. Moreover why don't u use simply `item_t0.TypePkString = 'N'`

Comment: Try this index: (p_internalurl, TypePkString).